# How to serialize a List of custom object types

Tags: c#, list, serialization, exception, xmlserializer

I have the class like this

```
public class Record
{
    public Int32 TotalTrail { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MyTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a List to hold objects of it:

```
List<Record> _records;
```

Then when I want to serialize the list:

serializer.Serialize(stream, _records);

There is a runtime error on the above line:

> Cannot assign object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SimpleGame.Record, SimpleGame, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to an object of type SimpleGame.Record.

Is it because I can't serialize the list? How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you create the `serializer`?

Comment: Note that XmlSerializer handles TimeSpan incorrectly (see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386602/system-timespan-xml-serialization, includes workaround).

Comment: could you paste the code that creates the serializer and then read the answers? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the serializer for the type `List<Record>` instead of `Record`

Comment: You don't need [Serializable] for XmlSerializer. Creating the serializer for the list type is fine though.

Comment: I'm not sure, so I changed the answer to a more flexible one

Comment: Oh! didn't realize he was talking about XmlSerializer specifically.

Comment: I haven't got chance to add how to create the serizlizer and you already guess what's wrong!! Thanks a lot! This solved my problem. I was pay much attention and now I learnt something today!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to implement serializable if you want to serialize to XML.  Below is a quick easy way to write any object to a file:

```
Dim s As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
Using fs As New IO.FileStream(thePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
    Using w As System.Xml.XmlTextWriter = New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        s = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
        w.Formatting = Xml.Formatting.Indented
        s.Serialize(w, m_objectToSerialize)
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify that your object is `Serializable`, following is the example.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Record 
{ 
    public Int32 TotalTrail { get; set; } 
    public TimeSpan MyTimeSpan { get; set; } 
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; } 
}
```

**Another Sol**

you can implement `ISerializable` interface

```
public class Record : ISerializable
{ 
    public Int32 TotalTrail { get; set; } 
    public TimeSpan MyTimeSpan { get; set; } 
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Neither of these apply to XmlSerializer

Comment: well, initially he didn't specified that he's using `XMLSerializer`

Comment: the tag is in the initial version (before the edit by another user)

Comment: I guess it was a rookie mistake....will be little more careful next time...still useful information though, appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class serializable ... Check this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx

Comment: This doesn't apply to XmlSerializer at all

Comment: the tag is in the initial version (before the edit by another user)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem:
What I did was, I went to the class which you made a list for and added a parameter-less constructor. I read somewhere that serialization works with parameter-less constructors. Once I did this. It worked like a charm! hope it worked..
Something Like this

```
public class InventoryType
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoomT { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public InventoryType() { }

    public InventoryType(DateTime date, int id, string roomT, int quantity)
    {

        this.Date = date;
        this.ID = id;
        this.RoomT = roomT;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {           
        return "Date: " + Date + "\nID: " + ID + "\nRoom Type: " + RoomT + "\nQuantity: " + Quantity;
    }
}
```